# How to set all ones in a matrix to zero except the first of every column?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix show as below in matlab :

```
[ 1 0 1;0 1 1;1 1 0 ]
```

How to refine it into this matrix show as below ?

```
[ 1 0 1;0 1 0; 0 0 0 ]
```

That means I just only want to take the first 1 appears in each column.

Thanks!

Comment: @user3509735 Welcome to StackOverflow! If there is an answer which answers your question suffiently mark it as solved. (green check mark on the left side of every question). It indicates your happiness to both system and answerers ;)

Answer (score 4):

One of probably many possibilities:

```
result = ( cumsum(A,1) == A ) & A

result =

     1     0     1
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

**Explanation:** `cumsum(A,1) == A` filters out all lower `1` and `... & A` sets upper zeros back to zero, as they got ones the step before.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: use `max` to get the row and column indices of the first one in each column. This is possible because the second output of `max` gives the position of the *first* maximum of each column.

```
[val, row] = max(A);
col = find(val); %// if max value is 0 => there aren't any 1's in that column
result = zeros(size(A));
result(sub2ind(size(A),row,col)) = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but shouldn't you transpose `A` in the first line? -> `max(A')`

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks. I think it's correct as it stands: `row` gives the (row) position of the maximum of each column, and `val` gives its value (which will be used to find columns).